# Is there a way to make C macros keyword agnostic?

Tags: c++, c, macros

Is there a way to concatenate keywords in a macro and get
C to behave in a more dynamic fashion as in:

```
#define macro(fun,ction,var,iable) function(variable)
```

I know this kind of thing exists in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ## to concatinate names in macros

fun##ction ...

Answer (score 2):

No. Although there is `##` as Michael says, it is applied (as all preprocessing) before C or C++ looks at keywords, and even using it to generate any preprocessing keyword is allowed to crash the preprocessor.

So, as a rule, if something doesn't compile when you input it directly, it won't when generated by the preprocessor either.

Answer (score 0):

There are some caveats to its use (e.g. you've got to jump through some hoops to concatenate the *results* of other macro expansions), but the GCC docs discuss the basic form:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Comment: You should add at least a short explanation and not just throw a link into the room.

Comment: It was my original intention to edit it to include an example but about four different people beat me to the chase so I didn't waste my time (I also didn't want to seem like I was copying their answer)